# Does pdfjs-dist can run with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pdf, pdfjs-dist

I want to preview pdf as canvas but I can't import pdfjs-dist in my project.

I've already installed pdfjs-dist using `$yarn add pdfjs-dist`

Do I have to import anything else?

```js
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"; //<-- Here is the problem.

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'. 'd:/pdf-genarator/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

If I remove `../build/pdf`;

```js
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

It doesn't show an error here but when I run this the console said

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GlobalWorkerOptions') . . .
```

Comment: TypeScript is complaining because you don't have a type for the package. It does mean that it will not run. Either check the package itself or ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with imports :

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf';
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.worker.entry';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;
const pdfjsLib = pdfjs;
```